# Как сделать общую функцию на удаление из разных таблиц на php?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, delete

У меня есть множество таблиц. И когда мне нужно удалить какую-нибудь запись, я использую для каждой таблицы свой, но почти одинаковый код. Я пыталась написать общую функцию, с передачей параметров через переменные, но оно никак не работает. А найти что-то подобное я не могу в интернете. Может гуглю не так...
Вот такая функция:

```
<?php
function delete($id, $table, $place) 
{
    require_once('../connect.php');

    // $id = $_GET['id'];

    // $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM $table WHERE id = $id");
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute(); 

    header ("Location: ../$place.php");
}
?>
```

Вот вызов этой функции и подключение файла:

```
require_once('moderator/delete_function.php');
delete($id, "fandoms", "fandoms");
```

Хотя вот этот вариант работает хорошо с конкретными значениями без переменных.

```
require_once '../connect.php';

    $id = $_GET['id'];

     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM fandoms WHERE id = ?");
     $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
     $stmt->execute(); 

    // require_once('delete_function.php');
    // delete($id, 'fandoms', 'fandoms');

    header ('Location: ../fandoms.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что у вас опечатка в запросе, где подставляется `$id` вместо `?` для параметра:

```php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: А даа, я это не исправила. Просто я много вариантов уже перепробовала, но так, тоже не работает.

Comment: Ругается на строчку $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE id = ?");  Warning: Undefined variable $mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\libreria\moderator\delete_function.php on line 9

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\libreria\moderator\delete_function.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\libreria\moderator\delete_fandom.php(12): delete('27', 'fandoms', 'fandoms') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\libreria\moderator\delete_function.php on line 9

Comment: А где вы создаете коннект к базе типа `$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_database');`?

Comment: Вот в подключенном файле connect.php   ```<?php

 define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
 define('DB_USER', 'root');
 define('DB_PASS', '');
 define('DB_NAME', 'libreria');

 $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
 if ($mysqli->connect_error) 
 {
  die('Ошибка подключения ('.$mysqli->connect_errno.')'.$mysqli->connect_error);
 }

?>```

Answer (score 0):

Оо, у меня заработало!
я заменила require_once на require и все встало на свои места.
код пока такой:

```
<?php 
//delete_funtion.php
function delete_zz(int $id, string $table, string $place) 
{
    require'../connect.php';

    // $id = $_GET['id'];

    // $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM $table WHERE id = $id");
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();  

    // $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM ? WHERE id = ?");
    // $stmt->bind_param("si", $table, $id);
    // $stmt->execute(); 

    header ("Location: ../$place.php");
}
?>
Это кнопка удаления в другом файле
<a class="moder_button" href="moderator/delete_fandom.php?id=<?=$info_fandoms['id'] ?>">Удалить</a>

<?php   
// delete_fandom.php
    require_once '../connect.php';

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    require_once('delete_function.php');
    delete_zz($id, 'fandoms', 'fandoms');

    header ('Location: ../fandoms.php');
?>
```